# How to make a forkjoinpool to compare two Arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, recursion, forkjoinpool

So i'm having a problem because i neet to make a recursive void to get the positions of the numbers that are the same but i d'ont know how to make it recursively.
i wass wondering if it's possible to make a forjoinpool without being a recursively void.

```
 
     public static int index(byte data [],int t, int start) {

           ArrayList <Integer> lista = new ArrayList();

           if(start == data.length) {
               System.out.println(data.length);
               return 0;
           }

           if(data[start]==t) {
               lista.add(start);
               return start;
           }
           return index(data,t,start+1);
       }
```

i need this void but instead of just searching for one number instead search in another array int t it has to be a byte target[]

Comment: Why make this recursive? This sounds unnecessary complex. --- What do you mean by "*i need this void*"? The method presented returns an `int`. --- I do not understand why we should use a `ForkJoinPool` for that problem. --- Please [edit] the post and clarify/improve where necessary.

Comment: so the task that i need to present one of the point is that the programm has to use forkjoinpool to resolve a return the byte[]array with the position of the macthed bytes

Comment: I still do not understand. Aside from the fact that I still doubt that a `ForkJoinPool` will speed up the process significantly (except we are working with really large arrays), tasks are described through either the `RecursiveAction`- or `RecrusiveTask`-interface. And I really do not understand why you want to use the `RecursiveAction` (or at least I think that is what you want to do), if we have a value to return and should thus use a `RecursiveTask`.